# Ruby statements - case insensitivity?

Tags: ruby, regex, boolean, case-insensitive, nomethoderror

I have a problem, I'm trying to create a method that finds words (or characters sequences)in a string and doesn't care about case sensitivity. For example both "ExAmPLE" and "example" would both return true. Here's my code

```
class WordMethods
  # Finds words in a string and returns true or false
  def word_finder?(string, word) # A boolean method that takes in one argument, word (a string)
    return true if string.include?(word, /i/) # trying to use regex for case insensitive
  end
word_finder?("A gold brown fox", "GoLD") # should return true
end
```

When I run the code on irb I get the following error.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `word_finder?' for WordMethods:Class
```

I don't understand. I defined my method inside the class, and then called it inside the class. I don't know where I'm going wrong. I am a beginner in ruby and practicing some example questions I found over the internet. This is one of them.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Do you care whether the substrings being searched for are whole words, or partial? Also, we use snake_case for method names in Ruby, not camelCase.

Comment: Doesn't matter at all. I just want to know if you can select a group of characters that appear in a string, and see if it finds them(ignoring case). I'll try to make that clearer in the OP

Comment: I think you need to find another Ruby tutorial. Judging by your code, you have some major misunderstands of how Ruby works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions in Ruby to search for something within a string, and make your search case-insensitive simply by adding `i` onto the end of the regular expression, like this:

```
"A gold brown fox" =~ /GoLD/i    #=> 2
```

This returns `2`, which is the index of the match. If there were no match, it would return `nil`. This works in a boolean context because the value `2` acts like "true" in Ruby, whereas `nil` acts as "false." Of course, if you really want it to return `true` or `false` you can prefix the expression with `!!` to force it to be a boolean:

```
!!("A gold brown fox" =~ /GoLD/i)   #=> true
```

This syntax is simple enough, but if you want to create a `word_finder?` method, you could do something like this:

```
class String
  def word_finder?(word)
    !!(self =~ Regexp.new(word, true))
  end
end

"A gold brown fox".word_finder?("GoLD")    #=> true
```

Three things to note with the code above:

1. We're monkey-patching the String class, adding a `word_finder?` method. This method is called by adding `.word_finder?` after a string, and the value of the string is represented within the function as `self`.
2. Creating a Regexp pattern via `Regexp.new(word, true)` returns a case-insensitive regular expression of that word. So, in this case, `Regexp.new("GoLD", true)` evaluates to `/GoLD/i`.
3. We enclose the `self =~ Regexp.new(word, true)` in `!!( ... )` so that we get `true` or `false`, not the index of the match or `nil`.

Reference:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#method-c-new
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-3D-7E